# How do I make 2x new picklist values show on opportunity?

Tags: opportunity, picklist

I created a picklist yesterday for sub contractors, This was fine and I added it to the opportunity page no problem and all choices are there.

Now I need to add 2x new subcontractors that were missed yesterday. 
I clicked the 'New' button in the picklist value section. Added the text and saved, then used re-order to make it display alphabetically on the opportunity.

The problem now is that the list has not been updated on the opportunity and the two new choices are not visible. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Kinds regards
Paul

p.s I cannot really send screen shots etc as this could be deemed as a breach in data protection.. Anything else I have blatantly missed or info you need to help, let me know.

Comment: check if there is record type exist or if this is dependent picklist then you need to add that as well

Comment: Hi Tushar, I am not too sure what that means If I am being honest. The picklist is not dependent on anything -- it was just a drop down list for a bunch of company names. I have a validation rule saying that if a tick box is checked then you must choose an option from the drop down list if this can have an effect?

Comment: You need to check record type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel this problem is linked to record types. Here are some steps to fix:

1. Login as Administrator. Go to Setup->customize->opportunities->Record Types.
2. A list of opportunity Record types would be displayed.
3. Click on record type name hyperlink of record type/record types where you want to configure new pick list options.
4. You can see all pick list fields on Record Type page including one that you modified.
5. click edit link for the field where you added new picklist values.
6. Move New values from Available values to Selected values and click Save.

Comment: You beautiful human being. Sorted, I have never had to mess with record types before and the system was already implemented before I started working here so no idea which one I had to edit. Anyway, the issue is resolved. Thank you very much! Have a great day